# Pregunta sobre la POO y las clases.Duda

Tags: python, poo

*Estoy aprendiendo  poo y me surgio una duda por que este codigo no funciona de la primer manera ,pero si de la segunda manera, que es cuando a la clase "Coche()" la pongo dentro de la variable "coche", quiero saber el por que funciona asi, por que si solo llamo a la clase no funciona.Estoy aprendiendo por videos asi que no tengo un profesor como tal a quien preguntar esta duda,espero no ocasionar problemas aqui preguntando.*

*Primer Forma

```
class Coche:
    # atributos o propiedades (variables)
    #caracteristicas del coche
    color = "Rojo"
    marca = "Ferrari"
    Modelo = "Aventador"
    velocidad = 300
    caballaje = 500
    plazas = 2

    # Metodos ,son acciones que hace el objeto (coche) (antes se les llamaba funcion)
    def setColor(self, paletaColor): # Ademas otra funcion de self,es que basicamente te va a dejar al usarla intereactuar con lo que haya dentro de la clase
        self.color = paletaColor    #con este metodo yo estoy cambiando el atributo o la variable de color

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color  #con esta funcion,o motodo,yo estoy llamando al atributo

    def setModelo(self, marca):
        self.Modelo = marca

    def getModelo(self):
        return self.Modelo

    def acelerar(self):  #con self entre los parametros se puede acceder a todos los atributos de una clase
        self.velocidad += 1

    def frenar(self):
        self.velocidad -=1

    def getVelocidad(self):
        return self.velocidad

    def getMarca(self):
        return self.marca

    def setMarca(self, marcaElegida):
        self.marca = marcaElegida


# Fin definicion clase

print("COCHE 1: ")

Coche().acelerar()
Coche().acelerar()
Coche().acelerar()

print(Coche().velocidad)
```

*Segunda Manera aqui es donde pongo la clase Coche dentro de la variable coche,y si funciona   al ejecutar,quiero saber por que de la otra manera no funciona

```
class Coche:
    # atributos o propiedades (variables)
    #caracteristicas del coche
    color = "Rojo"
    marca = "Ferrari"
    Modelo = "Aventador"
    velocidad = 300
    caballaje = 500
    plazas = 2


    # Metodos ,son acciones que hace el objeto (coche) (antes se les llamaba funcion)
    def setColor(self, paletaColor): # Ademas otra funcion de self,es que basicamente te va a dejar al usarla intereactuar con lo que haya dentro de la clase
        self.color = paletaColor    #con este metodo yo estoy cambiando el atributo o la variable de color

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color  #con esta funcion,o motodo,yo estoy llamando al atributo

    def setModelo(self, marca):
        self.Modelo = marca

    def getModelo(self):
        return self.Modelo

    def acelerar(self):  #con self entre los parametros se puede acceder a todos los atributos de una clase
        self.velocidad += 1


    def frenar(self):
        self.velocidad -=1

    
    def getVelocidad(self):
        return self.velocidad

    def getMarca(self):
        return self.marca

    def setMarca(self, marcaElegida):
        self.marca = marcaElegida

coche = Coche()

print("COCHE 1: ")

coche.acelerar()
coche.acelerar()
coche.acelerar()

print(coche.velocidad)
```

Comment: Al hacer `Coche()` estas creando un nuevo tipo de dato (creando una instancia de la clase `Coche`) es decir que cada vez que hagas `Coche()` estás creando un nuevo objeto y al tener atributos de instancia significa que cada Coche es independiente, lo que quiere decir que no compartirán sus atributos. En el primer caso estás creando una instancia cada vez, lo que quiere decir que estás creando 4 coches distintos. En la segunda forma solo creas uno y luego vas modificando sus atributos.

Comment: Hola!, `Coche` es solo la clase que has creado, lo que te falta es crear una variable que sea de la clase `Coche`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

lo que pasa es que en la segunda forma estás instanciando a la clase, de tal forma que puedes acceder a sus métodos/atributos y es por ello que te resulta; esa es la forma correcta.

De la primera manera, estás accediendo directamente a la clase, lo cuál es incorrecto, ya que en POO no se puede instanciar a una clase directamente porque esta hereda de la clase general o madre de todas que es `Object`.

A esto se llama crear una instancia de un objeto:

```
coche = Coche()
```

Comment: Por favor explícate mejor. ¿Cómo que no se puede instanciar una clase directamente?

Comment: No se puede instanciar a la clase object directamente y eso sucede cuando llamas a un objeto de una clase en específico por ejemplo `Coche().acelerar()`; es erróneo, hay que crear instancia de la clase `Coche` para acceder a sus métodos.

Comment: Nop, estás equivocado